# Error al mapear entidades desde la base de datos: org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.ValidationException

Tags: java, sql-server, jpa

Estoy desarrollando una aplicación en [windows7](/questions/tagged/windows7) con [netbeans](/questions/tagged/netbeans) 8.1 y una base de datos SQL Server 2012. He mapeado las entidades directamente desde la base de datos pero al momento de iniciar mi aplicación me aparece este error:

> Grave: Exception while preparing the app : Exception [EclipseLink-28018] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.5.0.v20130507-3faac2b):
>
> org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.EntityManagerSetupException
>
> Exception Description: Predeployment of PersistenceUnit [SEFARCOL_PU] failed.
>
> Internal Exception: Exception [EclipseLink-7250] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.5.0.v20130507-3faac2b):
>
> org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.ValidationException
>
> Exception Description: [class com.mycompany.sefarcoldatos.Lineaproduccion] uses a non-entity [class com.mycompany.sefarcoldatos.Tipolinea] as target entity in the relationship attribute [field idtipolinea].

¿Alguien sabe por qué sucede esa excepción?¿Y qué puedo hacer para corregirla?

Comment: Por favor añade la configuración pertinente, ademas creo que el mensaje es bastante descriptivo, te dice ***"LineaProduccion utiliza una clase TipoLinea no entity"***, utiliza **@Entity** en dicha clase, mapea de forma correcta todas tus clases de dominio

Comment: IDE netbeans 8.1

Comment: DB sqlserver2012

Comment: Sistema operativo windows 7 professional

Comment: Las entidades fueron mapeadas directamente desde la base de datos pero al momento de iniciar mi aplicacion me aparece ese error

Comment: Pues revisa el mapeo que te ha generado, parece que el atributo **idtipolinea** de la entidad ***Tipolinea*** tiene algún problema

Comment: Asegurate que tienes declaradas todas tus entity class en el **persistence.xml** y que ademas estan todas en el mismo JAR.

Comment: Sin mas información no te podemos ayudar mucho, usas anotaciones o configuración xml?

Answer (score 0):

> Exception Description: [class com.mycompany.sefarcoldatos.Lineaproduccion] uses a non-entity [class com.mycompany.sefarcoldatos.Tipolinea] as target entity in the relationship attribute [field idtipolinea].

El mapeo no se realizó correctamente entre las entidades Lineaproduccion y Tipolinea en el campo idtipolinea.

Tipolinea no es una entidad o no está dentro del archivo `persistence.xml`.

Answer (score 0):

En el logo puedo ver dos errores el primero es:

- Esta excepción se da cuando no tienes agregada tu tabla al `persistence.xml` lo puedes hacer de esta manera, por lo general se encuentra en `src\main\resources\META-INF\persistence.xml`

  ```
  <class>nombre de tu paquete y clase</class>
  ```
- Por ultimo algunas veces cuando tenemos columnas tipo `Date()` y para ello tienes que agregarle esta anotación donde las mapeaste

  ```
  @Temporal(javax.persistence.TemporalType.DATE)
  ```

Answer (score 0):

A mi me parece que estas usando una libreria incorrecta para la conexión por eso no entiende las relaciones, o en tu base de datos no estas usando los campos que tu libreria entiende, es decir si usas la libreria del 4.0 para atras y usas tipos de datos BIGINT, IMAGE, MONEY, VARBINARY...etc 

Debes usar librerias actuales. 
En mi caso uso la 7.0, con el nombre de busqueda: mssql-jdbc-7.0.0.jre8 
puedes buscar en las paginas de microsoft o tambien en este link. [Mega driver 7.0 Microsoft SQL Server](https://mega.nz/#F!q8ARgY4Z!tt80xHPOQjtbVJl5_kQlnw)